# Accidentally removed admin rights on a folder in business objects

Tags: business-objects, administrator

I created a new folder in business objects, instead of removing the access right of Everyone user group, I set 'No Access' right from Administrator user group. Now I cannot remove the folder on my admin account, neither from the users within the Everyone user group as this group does not have delete right on the folder. Is there a way to delete the folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to fix the problem. My admin account has full control right to the parent folder of the new folder, from the parent folder, I enabled the 'Delete' right to its child folders, this then allowed me delete the new folder.